# How to fix "temporary value dropped here while still borrowed" when trying to .find() value in const array?

Tags: arrays, rust, iterator

I have an array defined in the form of a constant, outside any function:

```
const VALUES: [(char, &str); 2] = [('A', "abc"), ('B', "acb")];
```

I'm attempting to use the [`find()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.find) method located on the `Iterator`, in order to extract a single element from an array based on a predicate:

```
VALUES.iter().find(|&&(name, _)| name == 'A');
```

In this form, it works fine. I am, however, unable to evaluate the found element into anything, as as soon as I attempt creating a `let` binding, trying to bind the result, which, according to the docs should come back as an `Option<T>`.

Let's change the second line to that which doesn't work:

```
const VALUES: [(char, &str); 2] = [('A', "abc"), ('B', "acb")];

fn main() {
    let result = VALUES.iter().find(|&&(name, _)| name == 'A');
}
```

([Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?code=const%20VALUES%3A%20%5B(char%2C%20%26str)%3B%202%5D%20%3D%20%5B(%27A%27%2C%20%22abc%22)%2C%20(%27B%27%2C%20%22acb%22)%5D%3B%0A%0Afn%20main()%0A%7B%0A%20%20%20%20let%20result%20%3D%20VALUES.iter().find(%7C%26%26(name%2C%20_)%7C%20name%20%3D%3D%20%27A%27)%3B%0A%7D%0A&version=stable&backtrace=0))

One would expect this to return the `Option<T>` as according to the docs, but instead I get back a compilation error:

```
error: borrowed value does not live long enough
 --> src/main.rs:4:63
  |
4 |     let result = VALUES.iter().find(|&&(name, _)| name == 'A');
  |                  ------ temporary value created here          ^ temporary value dropped here while still borrowed
5 | }
  | - temporary value needs to live until here
  |
  = note: consider using a `let` binding to increase its lifetime
```

I'm utterly confused; I'm certain I've just messed up with the "borrow checker". Perhaps someone can point me in the right direction?

Comment: I asked a concise Question for common rust error `error[E0716]` [error E0716: temporary value dropped while borrowed (rust)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71626083/error-e0716-temporary-value-dropped-while-borrowed-rust). It links back to this Question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in the specific way you're turning that array into an iterator.

First of all, `const`s in Rust do not actually exist anywhere.  Instead, they're substituted by-value everywhere they're used.  So every time you use a constant, you're getting a new copy of it.

Secondly, you're using `IntoIterator::into_iter`.  This takes the subject *by value* and converts it into an iterator.

These combine with the third part: `IntoIterator` is *not* implemented for fixed-size arrays.  It's only implemented for *pointers* to fixed-size arrays.  So, in order to invoke `into_iter`, the compiler has to insert an automatic borrow of the invocant.

So, what's actually happening is this:

```
let t = {
    // Make a new copy of `VALUES`.
    let values: [(char, &str); 5] = VALUES;
    // Borrow it.
    let values: &[_] = &values;
    // Call `into_iter` on the borrow.
    IntoIterator::into_iter(values).find(|&&(name, _)| name == 'A')
};
```

This causes problems because the compiler has to simultaneously copy *and* borrow `VALUES` in order to get an iterator.  Like all temporaries, said copy only lives as long as the statement, but the borrow (by being bound to a variable) has to live longer than that.

The best solution is to make `VALUES` a *pointer* to the array.  This prevents copying the entire array; instead, you only copy the pointer on each use.

```
const VALUES: &[(char, &str)] = &[...];
```

Alternately, you could explicitly make a copy of `VALUES` and store it in a variable, then use `into_iter` on *that*.  However, like before, this will introduce unnecessary copying.

Comment: Const arrays actually exist in memory. [This code](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=023a4c4ea0cc8cac7a890bbd3a05d876&version=stable&backtrace=0) works. The temporary value that gets dropped isn't array, it's array slice.

Comment: @red75prime: My understanding is that *that* behaviour is a special case where temporaries that are immediately borrowed are promoted, as that pattern is relatively common and would otherwise be more painful.

Comment: Another option is to use `static`, which actially does exist in memory and therefore can be borrowed normally.

Answer (score 1):

[DK.'s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44614412/155423) is correct, but I'd suggest a simpler change to get your code to work — use `static` instead of `const`.

From the [documentation about static and const](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/first-edition/const-and-static.html):

> More specifically, constants in Rust have no fixed address in memory.

> static items aren’t inlined upon use. This means that there is only one instance for each value, and it’s at a fixed location in memory.

Switching to `static` allows you to get a memory address of the thing you are iterating over.

```
static VALUES: [(char, &str); 2] = [('A', "abc"), ('B', "acb")];

fn main() {
    let result = VALUES.iter().find(|&&(name, _)| name == 'A');
}
```

Here, `result` is an `Option<&(char, &str)>`.